Could a reliable data transfer protocol over serial UART benefit from a TCP-like sliding window or stop and wait is good enough?
The obvious complexity of TCP is designed for a long distance communication over multiple hops and packet loss and packet rearrangement are all too common. In contrast, UART is peer-to-peer typically over a very short distance.  But data corruption could be an issue as the cable length increases. So it does need a reliable protocol.  But I am not sure if it could benefit for a sliding window. Perhaps a simple stop-and-wait ARQ could be good enough for performance and reliability.

"But data corruption could be an issue as the cable length increases. So it does need a reliable protocol. " - The reliability in TCP is not about dealing with lots of data corruption, but about packet loss. To handle lots of data corruption you need better mechanism than the simple checksum TCP offers. Better look for this how other data link layer protocols handle this instead of trying to address this on the transport layer.

But data corruption could be an issue as the cable length increases. - then simple checksumming and repeat-sending-until-success might not be good enough. This is an issue with a serial link and not a networking question. Better look up forward error correction FEC.

Sliding window does not create a reliable transport, it just allows the exiting medium to stay full by eliminating any delay waiting for an ACK or additional request. (eg, TFTP)

Absolutely,  this is why zmodem exists.  possibly on-topic in retrocomputing.
